# Yii2 assets across multiple servers

Tags: yii2, assets

I'm trying to deploy yii2-app to multiple servers. But I have no idea how to share assets. Problem: By default server generates assets when someone loads a view. But I have multiple servers, and a browser may request an assets (js or css file) from another server, that doesn't have any assets yet.

Probably, it needs to create all assets on each server with the same paths during deploy, but how?

Comment: What's your way to share app between servers?

Comment: You'd better not access any files inside of assets folder directly.  Use AssetBundle to manage your css, js file. Yii2 will create those files into assets folder for you.

Comment: Why not to use nginx for redirecting static files requests between nodes?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function actionCreateBackend()
    {
        Yii::setAlias('@webroot', __DIR__.'/../../backend/web');
        Yii::setAlias('@web', '/');

        \backend\assets\AppAsset::register($this->getView());

        echo 'Backend assets was created successfully.'.PHP_EOL;
        return 0;
    }
```

Don't forget use `hashCallback` of assetManager for generating identical asset path